# Unable to parse AuthnRequest from SAML 2.0 Service Provider

Tags: saml

My aim is service provider-initiated Web SSO profile. I am implementing the service provider (SP), using Salesforce as the identity provider (IDP) for testing my SP. Can I use Salesforce IDP?

I have configured Salesforce as my test identity provider for my service provider [I am implementing the SP using the OpenSAML library].

**"Edit 1 start"**

**First of all , can we use salesforce IdP for the sp(locally hosted) intiated sso web profile? I wanted to send my request message to salesForce IdP from my program ***

[adding my request messages]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><samlp:AuthnRequest xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" AssertionConsumerServiceURL="http://localhost:8080/test_with_OpenSAML/AssertionConsumerService.jsp" ID="7ickdmjo241394083307023" IssueInstant="2014-03-06T05:21:47.115Z" ProtocolBinding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" ProviderName="ls" Version="2.0"><saml:Issuer xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">http://localhost:8080/test_with_OpenSAML</saml:Issuer></samlp:AuthnRequest>
```

: In the case of **HTTP Redirect** , deflating , base64 and url encoding should be done.

after deflating(with zero compression ):SAME REQUEST MESSAGE AS ABOVE
[what level of deflating level should I use?]

after base64 encoding :

```
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
```

after URLencoded :[ONLY THE SAMLRequest message should be url encoded]

```
PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0iVVRGLTgiPz48c2FtbHA6QXV0aG5SZXF1ZXN0IHhtbG5zOnNhbWxwPSJ1cm46b2FzaXM6bmFtZXM6dGM6U0FNTDoyLjA6cHJvdG9jb2wiIEFzc2VydGlvbkNvbnN1bWVyU2VydmljZVVSTD0iaHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdDo4MDgwL3Rlc3Rfd2l0aF9PcGVuU0FNTC9Bc3NlcnRpb25Db25zdW1lclNlcnZpY2UuanNwIiBJRD0iN2lja2Rtam8yNDEzOTQwODMzMDcwMjMiIElzc3VlSW5zdGFudD0iMjAxNC0wMy0wNlQwNToyMTo0Ny4xMTVaIiBQcm90b2NvbEJpbmRpbmc9InVybjpvYXNpczpuYW1lczp0YzpTQU1MOjIuMDpiaW5kaW5nczpIVFRQLVBPU1QiIFByb3ZpZGVyTmFtZT0iY3YiIFZlcnNpb249IjIuMCI%2BPHNhbWw6SXNzdWVyIHhtbG5zOnNhbWw9InVybjpvYXNpczpuYW1lczp0YzpTQU1MOjIuMDphc3NlcnRpb24iPmh0dHA6Ly8xNzIuMTYuNjUuMTA6ODA4MC90ZXN0X3dpdGhfT3BlblNBTUw8L3NhbWw6SXNzdWVyPjwvc2FtbHA6QXV0aG5SZXF1ZXN0Pg%3D%3D
```

**http:xxx.salesforce.com/idp/endpoint/HttpRedirect?SAMLRequest=ABOVE_MESSAGE**

Is it mandatory to add RelayState?what it should contain?

**Edit 1 ends**

Once configured I have built the AuthnRequest and by using HTTP POST binding just appended the SAMLREQUEST="URLencodedAuthnRequest" to the POST binding URL of IDP [provided from IDP metadata]

When I send the request message, I see the **unable to parse AuthnRequest from service provider** error in the Identity Provider Event Log:

[image: Service provider is also unknown.why is that so? I have registered my SP as well]

Where am I going wrong? I have referred to all the [discussions in the Salesforce forums](https://developer.salesforce.com/search?q=unable%20to%20parse%20AuthnRequest%20from%20service%20provider), but I cant find the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the SAML 2.0 *POST* binding you have to POST the SAML request in a base64-encoded control within an HTML form - here's an example of what the service provider might send to the browser, from section 3.5.8 of the [SAML 2.0 Bindings Specification](http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-bindings-2.0-os.pdf):

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: 21 Jan 2004 07:00:49 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<body onload="document.forms[0].submit()">

<noscript>
<p>
<strong>Note:</strong> Since your browser does not support JavaScript,
you must press the Continue button once to proceed.
</p>
</noscript>

<form action="https://ServiceProvider.com/SAML/SLO/Browser"
method="post">
<div>
<input type="hidden" name="RelayState"
value="0043bfc1bc45110dae17004005b13a2b"/>
<input type="hidden" name="SAMLRequest"
value="PHNhbWxwOkxvZ291dFJlcXVlc3QgeG1sbnM6c2FtbHA9InVybjpvYXNpczpuYW1l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"/>
</div>
<noscript>
<div>
<input type="submit" value="Continue"/>
</div>
</noscript>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The SAML 2.0 *Redirect* binding uses a query parameter containing the request, compressed then base64-encoded. Here's an example from section 3.4.8 of the same document:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Object Moved
Date: 21 Jan 2004 07:00:49 GMT
Location:
https://ServiceProvider.com/SAML/SLO/Browser?SAMLRequest=fVFdS8MwFH0f7D%
2BUvGdNsq62oSsIQyhMESc%2B%2BJYlmRbWpObeyvz3puv2IMjyFM7HPedyK1DdsZdb%2F%
2BEHfLFfgwVMTt3RgTwzazIEJ72CFqRTnQWJWu7uH7dSLJjsg0ev%2FZFMlttiBWADtt6R%
2BSyJr9msiRH7O70sCm31Mj%2Bo%2BC%
2B1KA5GlEWeZaogSQMw2MYBKodrIhjLKONU8FdeSsZkVr6T5M0GiHMjvWCknqZXZ2OoPxF7kG
naGOuwxZ%2Fn4L9bY8NC%
2By4du1XpRXnxPcXizSZ58KFTeHujEWkNPZylsh9bAMYYUjO2Uiy3jCpTCMo5M1StVjmN9SO1
50sl9lU6RV2Dp0vsLIy7NM7YU82r9B90PrvCf85W%2FwL8zSVQzAEAAA%3D%
3D&RelayState=0043bfc1bc45110dae17004005b13a2b&SigAlg=http%3A%2F%
2Fwww.w3.org%2F200%2F09%2Fxmldsig%23rsa-
sha1&Signature=NOTAREALSIGNATUREBUTTHEREALONEWOULDGOHERE
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

Salesforce will accept either binding, using the appropriate URL from the metadata. Render the HTML form, or use the redirect binding, whichever works best for you.

**Edit 1 start:**

You have `http://localhost:8080/test_with_OpenSAML` as the Issuer. This element should actually refer to the issuer of the SAML Assertion (the IdP). Use the value from the Identity Provider config in Salesforce - it will be something like `https://company-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com`.

<strike>Also, you have `ProtocolBinding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST"` in your request, but you're sending it via redirect. It should be `ProtocolBinding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect"`.</strike> *EDIT - this was incorrect - the ProtocolBinding identifies the protocol binding to use for the SAML response*

`RelayState` is optional. Whatever you pass here, the IdP will pass back to you with the SAML response. `RelayState` is typically used to hold the URL that the user originally requested, or some handle to that URL.

**Edit 1 end.**

Comment: I have tried HTTP redirect as u stated,still the same results persist.@metadaddy

Comment: Can you edit your question and paste in the request that you're sending?

Comment: also see this: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/29398/salesforce-identity-provider-configuration-for-the-local-service-provider Thank you.

Comment: You have the Issuer wrong in the request - see the edit I just made to my answer.

Comment: Did that fix the problem?

Comment: The issuer is wrong as you said.I corrected that.
ProtocolBinding of mine is correct.That is to notify the IdP to use that binding while sending the response back.

Comment: Am I correct in Protocol Binding in my previous comment?

Comment: Yes - you are right - SAML Core spec says that ProtocolBinding is "A URI reference that identifies a SAML protocol binding to be used when returning the <Response> message." - I'll edit my answer - thanks!